# ASP.net , jquery Uncaught TypeError: $ (...). autocomplete is not a function"

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Autocomplete does not work when you copy the sample source code into my cshml file, -> error "Uncaught TypeError: $ (...). autocomplete is not a function"
 what to do? I have links to .js fine, the same as in the source code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use Google CDN instead of Jquery. I tried using it and it works. I am looking on why Jquery CDN is giving issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting http:// infront of all the links and see if it works as below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
 <input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried putting http: // infront of all the links and it does not work.

Then I tried these links

  <Link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" />
     <Script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"> </ script>
     <Script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"> </ script>

and it does not work.

and it works on it then what links?

Comment: Can you replace them with this <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: So I finally solved. The problem was not in the links.
But I must add .Include ("~ / Scripts / jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js")); to  BundleCongif.cs.

This is not mentioned in any instructions!